Difference between [ngStyle] and [style] for inline styling in Angular
What's that difference between using [ngStyle] and [style.<attr>] for inline styling components in Angular?

Basically in ngStyle you can add conditional styles (eg: isLastElement ? /some-style/ : /some-style/) as well as normal style while in style you can only add normal styles.

In Angular, you can use either [ngStyle] or [style.<attr>] to apply inline styles to components. While both methods achieve similar results, there are key differences:
[ngStyle]

Accepts an object with CSS property names as keys and values as values.
Can be used to set multiple styles at once.
Supports property binding, allowing for dynamic style updates.

Example:
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'blue', 'color': 'white'}"> test text </div>

[style.<attr>]

Accepts a single CSS property value.
Can be used to set a single style attribute.
Also supports property binding for dynamic updates.

Example:
<div [style.background-color]="'blue'" [style.color]="'white'"> test text </div>

Key differences:

Multiple styles: [ngStyle] allows setting multiple styles at once, while [style.<attr>] requires separate bindings for each style attribute.

Object vs. single value: [ngStyle] expects an object, whereas [style.<attr>] expects a single value.

Readability and maintainability: For simple, single-style attributes, [style.<attr>] might be more readable. For multiple styles or more complex scenarios, [ngStyle] can be more convenient.


Ultimately, the choice between [ngStyle] and [style.<attr>] depends on your specific use case, personal preference, and the complexity of your styling needs.
Note: For more detail please take reference from here https://blog.angulartraining.com/whats-the-difference-between-style-and-ngstyle-in-angular-68a3301c2ae6


The main & obvious difference between [ngStyle] & [style] is in the output:

using [style.color]="condition ? 'black' : ''" will add a inline color style to the element in ALL the conditions (true or false)
but using [ngStyle]="condition && {'color':'black'}" will add a inline color style to the element ONLY when the condition is true


Other than this, [ngStyle] helps in styling with multiple conditions for a better developer experience. For example:

using [style.<attr>]: <div [style.color]="hasError ? 'red' : 'black' " [style.font]="font"       [style.background-color]="hasError ? 'tomato' : 'white' ">

using [ngStyle]:
<div [ngStyle]="currentStyles">

this.currentStyles = {     
    'font-style':  this.canSave  ? 'italic' : 'normal',  
    'color':       this.hasError ? 'red'   : 'black',     
    'font-size':   this.hasError ? '24px'   : '12px'   
};





References:

https://jscurious.com/ngstyle-vs-style-binding-in-angular/
https://blog.angulartraining.com/whats-the-difference-between-style-and-ngstyle-in-angular-68a3301c2ae6


I doubt that [style.color]="false ? 'black' : ''" will add anything to html element

It doesn't initially, but it does leave behind a valueless style attribute if the binding changes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gifzedyq
